# Have IBOutlet, but can't UIWebView to it

Tags: xcode4

I have this code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface slTableViewController : UITableViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>  {
 //   IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@end
```

And I have this UIWebView that I am trying to connect to "file's owner" (of course in XCode4, "file's owner" doesn't exist anymore, so I go from viewController to webView).  As you can see in this image (http://imgur.com/4KQJX), "webView" is not a choice, only "view".

This happens often, and I don't know how to fix it.  What is wrong, and how do I fix it?

UPDATED: code changed per suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `IBOutlet` when declaring the property:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
```

You can also get the `IBOutlet` generated automatically. When you are in Interface Builder, Open the **Assistant Editor** (red square in the screenshot) and control-drag the web view from Interface Builder to the `.h` file.

[image]

Comment: I did...here's what I think is wrong:  Using XCode4 with Storyboard, I have a UITableViewController with a bunch of TableViewCells, each of which is connected to another controller via segues (see http://imgur.com/RUdCZ).  Because the code to load the webView is located in the TableViewController, I don't see anyway to connect "webView" to TableViewController so it knows about "webView".